# Overwrite and Inherit a module from other package in python

Tags: python

I already have a project have a module name abc.py

I want to change and add some method in module abc.py but I do not want to modify abc.py because I want to keep entireness of that project.

So I create other module name abc.py in other package name myPackage

How when I install project and myPackage, my module abc.py can overwrite original module abc.py in that project

Thank

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would want to do that, but it is possible to do it in Python. Let me show you using the standard module `math`

```
import math as m

m.cos = lambda x: "I like pancakes"

print m.cos(12) # prints "I like pancakes"
```

Why can't you simply declare your new method outside of the mentioned module, and use it as such?

Comment: I rewrite my question for more detail, pls read again my idea, thanks

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't sound like a sane approach.  What you could do is define `my_abc.py` with something like

```
from abc import *

def overridden_method (args):
    "Your overridden method here."
    pass
```

Now `my_abc.foo` refers indirectly to the underlying `abc.foo` while `my_abc.overridden_method` refers specifically and directly to the overridden method in your wrapper package.

This is a bit murky, though; if `abc` is a class, the vastly preferred method is to define a new class which inherits from it.

```
from abc import Abc

class MyAbc (Abc):  # MyAbc inherits from the Abc class
    def overridden_method (self, arguments):
        "Your overridden method replaces anything with the same name in Abc."
        pass
```

Now a `MyAbc()` object instance is basically identical to an `Abc()` object instance from the class you inherited from, but its `overridden_method` method will be the one you defined in `myabc.py`.

Comment: I rewrite my question for more detail, pls read again my idea, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the imports made in every module where you want to use the new abc.py .

from myPackage.abc import *

Comment: I rewrite my question for more detail, pls read again my idea, thanks